# Problema con Login de Facebook en app ya subida al play Store

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-api

Tengo una app que anteriormente ya tenia subida al play store sin login de ningun tipo, actualmente le realize mejoras y la subi al play store (entre ellas el login con facebook) el problema es que al ejecutarla desde android studio todo funciona bien pero al usar la version del play store (que es la misma de android studio) me rechaza la obtencion de datos. Por lo que estuve investigando es un problema de hashes de la configuracion en facebook developers... Pero no encuentro la solucion. Espero haber sido claro. Gracias

EDIT: La solucion fue tambien enviar el hash de la app que brinda play store al subir la app

Comment: Localmente trabajas con ambientes de desarrollo o sandbox de las API, al publicar debes cambiar los token (si lo tienes) a ambientes de producción de Facebook. Deberías revisar esa parte.

Comment: No sabria decirte que es ambiente de desarrollo  o sandbox. Trabajo con java y android studio

Comment: Tu id o token , tienes que cambiarlo por el que te da android studio al crear tu apk o tu app bundle.